# How to get the name of file that triggerred nodemon restart?

Tags: jsx, nodemon, babel-cli

I have some JSX files in my `src` directory. I use babel cli to compile them and nodemon to watch for changes in these files.

```
nodemon --watch src --exec "npx babel src -d bin"
```

However, at each restart all the files in src are compiled even though only one file was changed. Is there a way to get the name of file that triggered nodemon restart, so that I can compile only that file?